# The order of the for loops affect the outcome

Tags: python

When running the following codes. Only loop 1 will be executed the loop 2 is gone. However if i move loop 1 behind loop2, both of the loops will be executed. Why is that ?
Thank you

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:

    count = 1

    #loop 1
    for i in file:
        print("Sequence {} :{}  Length: {}".format(count, i[:20], len(i)))
        count += 1
    count -= 1
    print("There are %d sequences." % count)  # count = 10

    #loop2
    for i in range(count):
        seq = file.readline()
        print(seq)
        # try:
        #     with open('dna_lab5_%d.xml' % i, 'r') as f:
        #         print("Using saved file")
        # except FileNotFoundError:
        #     print("Performing online BLAST search")
        #     with open('dna_lab5_%d.xml' % i, 'w') as f:
        #         print(seq)
        #         # handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", seq)
        #         # result = handle.read()
        #         # f.write(result)
```

Comment: What is the content of "input.txt"?

Comment: file can only be iterated over once. it gets consumed. try running `file.read()` twice.

Comment: *Only loop 1 will be executed the loop 2 is gone*. That's false. `loop2` **is** executed. However `file.readline()` will always return the empty string. Please describe your problem accurately. The issue is that the first loop is going to iterate over the file object until the end, so no content remains for the `readline` method to return.

Comment: When iterating over a file directly, such as using `for line in file`, it will read through the whole file. If you use `file.readline()` instead, it will only give one line and you can control the amount you want to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've consumed the file handle already in the first loop. A simple example might be:

```py
with open('afile.txt') as fh:
    # this will consume fh
    for line in fh:
        print(line)

    print(fh.readline()) # prints empty string, because there's nothing left to read

    for line in fh:
        print(line) # won't do anything because you've already read everything
```

If you want to read a file twice, you can use `fh.seek(0)` to go back to the beginning:

```py
with open('afile.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print(line)

    fh.seek(0)
    # now this works
    for line in fh:
        print(line)
```